# fillna() not replacing NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am new to the machine learning world and havent practiced alot of Python. i was trying to do mean imputation but the Nan values wont get replaced.

```
df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)
print(df.isnull().sum())
print(df.tail(17))
```

[ive added the output image with the NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQrM8.png)

Comment: Can u show us what is the ouput ur getting.

Comment: `df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)` works for me to fill NaNs with column means. A sample of dummy data that demonstrates your problem would help a lot.

Comment: Your code seems ok. However without data, we can not see if it does what you expect

Comment: I got the error. All the colums that i was looking at had non numeric values. thanks a ton